# ClearMyTracksByProcess 10554 slowing down Win7 PC (rundll32.exe inetcpl.cpl)

Tags: windows-7, performance, rundll32.exe

Here's complete info from the Command Line in Task Manager:

`rundll32.exe C:\Windows\system32\inetcpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 10554`

There are 2 of those running, taking up 150K to 900k memory & 5 - 30% CPU. I end them, and everything's fine. After a few days, they return.

They seem to run after I use something with Audio &/or Video, e.g., Zune, iTunes, GoToMeeting, Pandora, but I can't pin it down to any one application. I say "seems" because maybe it's not related at all.

Comment: Run Process Explorer from Sysinternals and see what it's parent is.

Comment: It says Parent: <Non-existent Process>(3532)

Comment: Is there anything else someone would need to help diagnose this?

Comment: Ok, so I'm not sure what the "bumping" policy is here, or if it's time to just give up on this, but I'm sort of clueless on what else to do at this point. It continues to get worse, and yesterday 4 of these processes were going at the same time taking up 900kb each.

Answer (score 3):

Hey guess what? I get to answer my own question! After tons of Googling, Trial, & Error, I finally discovered that it had to do with Internet Explorer. Specifically, whenever I closed IE8, those processes ran (and never stopped). I finally tracked down the culprit: In Internet Options, I had Delete browsing history on exit checked. Unchecking that fixed it. So apparently, on exit, it ran a couple of processes to clear history but somehow was foobared.

Comment: Had the same problem on Vista, your solution worked !